# Finding locations of repeated 0 in a binary list

Tags: python, list, group-by, binary, python-itertools

I've got a binary list returned from a k means classification with k = 2, and I am trying to 1) identify the number of 0,0,0,... substrings of a given length -  say a minimum of length 3, and 2) identify the start and end locations of these sublists, so in a list: `L = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]`, the outputs would ideally be: `number = 2` and `start_end_locations = [[2,6],[13,15]]`.
The lists I'm working with are tens of thousands of elements long, so I need to find a computationally fast way of performing this operation. I've seen many posts using `groupby` from `itertools`, but I can't find a way to apply them to my task.
Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip() to detect indexes of the 1,0 and 0,1 breaks in sequence.  Then use zip() on the break indexes to form ranges and extract the ones that start with a zero and span at least 3 positions.

```
def getZeroStreaks(L,minSize=3):
    breaks = [i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(L,L[1:]),1) if a!=b]
    return [[s,e-1] for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks+[len(L)])
                        if e-s>=minSize and not L[s]]
```

output:

```
L = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]
print(getZeroStreaks(L))
[[2, 6], [13, 15]]

from timeit import timeit

t = timeit(lambda:getZeroStreaks(L*1000),number=100)/100

print(t) # 0.0018 sec for 16,000 elements
```

The function can be generalized to find streaks of any value in a list:

```
def getStreaks(L,N=0,minSize=3):
    breaks = [i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(L,L[1:]),1) if (a==N)!=(b==N)]
    return [[s,e-1] for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks+[len(L)])
                         if e-s>=minSize and L[s]==N]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

- craft a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) that matches your pattern: *three or more zeros*
- *concatenate* the list items to a string
- using re.finditer and match object start() and end() methods construct a list of indices

Concatenating the lists to a string could be the most expensive part - you won't know till you try; finditer should be pretty quick. Requires more than one pass through the data but probably low *effort* to code.

---

This will probably be better - a single pass through the list but you need to pay attention to the logic - more effort to code.

- iterate over the list using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- when you find a **zero**

  - *capture* its index and
  - set a flag indicating you are tracking zeros
- when you find a **one**

  - if you are tracking zeros

    - capture the index
    - if the length of consecutive zeros meets your criteria *capture* the start and end indices for that run of zeros
  - reset flags and intermediate variables as necessary

---

A bit different than the *word* version:

```
def g(a=a):
    y = []
    criteria = 3
    start,end = 0,0
    prev = 1
    for i,n in enumerate(a):
        if not n:        # n is zero
            end = i
            if prev:     # previous item one
                start = i
        else:
            if not prev and end - start + 1 >= criteria:
                y.append((start,end))
        prev = n
    return y
```